# How do I get category and page ID's?

Tags: categories, pages

I want to insert the category or page ID of the current page into my HTML so that I can use CSS to style each page based on what it is.

For example, if had a category called "News" and it's ID was 5, my source code would end up having  in it. Then I could use CSS to style #category-id-5 to suit my needs.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) has a property with that ID.

But you don't really need it, because the `<body>` tag should have a class with the current category / page ID...

Comment: For whatever reason the theme I'm using didn't have this functionality already added to the body tag. And unfortunately get_queried_object() didn't work for me.

    <?php $my-page = $wp_query -> get_queried_object() ?>
    <body class="my-page-<?php echo $my-page ?>">

Comment: it should be `my_page->ID`, and `my_page->term_id` for categories